# In rm, what is recursive about the recursive modifier -R?

Tags: rm

I watched an introductory video on using the command line in ubuntu. 
It states that in order to erase a directory that is not empty,
you can not use `rmdir`, but `rm -R`. He called "-R" the recursive modifier. 
Now, from python, I know that recursive means "calling itself". But I don't see what is calling itself here.

When I tried to look online for info about the general meaning of `-R`, all I found are instructions on how to use it in commands, but no explanations about it itself.

Can someone here explain this to me? not only in the `rm` context, but in a general way - what is recursive about `-R` and when to use it?

Comment: Command line options are command specific. There is no general meaning.

Comment: File systems are recursive in the sense that directories can contain not just files, but also other directories (which can contain more directories, etc).

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's scope is limited to *software development*; questions about usage of UNIX tools that aren't specific to that purpose should be asked at our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Recursive" in this context means that the program traverses a directory hierarchy, which is a recursive data structure (a tree), since a directory can contain other directories. As well, the program might use recursion internally to do the traversal. For more details, see [Filesystem traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Filesystem_traversal) and other sections on the Wikipedia page "Recursion (computer science)".

Answer (score 0):

Truly, the directories are structured like a tree, this means that starting from a specific folder you will find children; these can be files or other folders. Each of these in turn can have children (files / folders), and so on ...